# DRYing a stateless functional builder

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

This was just an experiment to see if it was possible to build a stateless builder in ES6. I was able to do it, but when I took it a step further I got stuck trying to DRY it out.

In this case, we have a `MoveableBuilder` and a `ParticleBuilder`. A `Particle` is a `Moveable`, so the `ParticleBuilder` could reuse a lot of the code from the `MoveableBuilder`. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to combine the two functions in an elegant way.

```js
function ParticleBuilder(coordinates = [], vector = [], lifespan = 255, decay = 1) {
  const self = this;
  
  this.at = (...coordinates) => 
    new self.constructor(coordinates, vector, lifespan, decay);
  
  this.facing = (...vector) => 
    new self.constructor(coordinates, vector, lifespan, decay);
  
  this.lifespan = (lifespan) => 
    new self.constructor(coordinates, vector, lifespan, decay);
  
  this.decay = (decay) => 
    new self.constructor(coordinates, vector, lifespan, decay);
  
  this.build = () => Object.freeze({
    coordinates: coordinates,
    vector: vector,
    lifespan: lifespan,
    decay: decay
  });
}

function MoveableBuilder(coordinates = [], vector = []) {
  const self = this;
  
  this.at = (...coordinates) => new self.constructor(coordinates, vector);
  
  this.facing = (...vector) => new self.constructor(coordinates, vector);
  
  this.build = () => Object.freeze({
    coordinates: coordinates,
    vector: vector
  });
}

console.info(new MoveableBuilder().at(1,1).facing(2,1).build());

console.info(new ParticleBuilder().at(1, 1).build());
```

What I had trouble with is how to reuse the `at` and `facing` methods within the `ParticleBuilder`. Granted, since the signatures of both builders is different, it might not be the correct thing to do. However, I figured I could elicit the community for feedback on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution and I think this is elegant, but I'm unsure if this is something that should be avoided or not since I'm fairly new to ES6.

Here are the following things I did to refactor it:

1. Unify the `Builder` signatures to use a single parameter `product`
2. Invoke the parent constructor within the child constructor with the same arguments on the instance.
3. Move the defaults into the `build` step of the `Builder`.
4. Use `Object.assign` to merge new properties.

There's a bit more that can be done to clean this up even further, but hopefully, this could be useful for someone else. One could repeat step 2 to include multiple `Builders` as well.

```js
function ParticleBuilder(product) {
  MoveableBuilder.call(this, product);
  this.lifespan = (lifespan) =>
    new this.constructor(Object.assign({}, product, {
      lifespan: lifespan
    }));

  this.decay = (decay) =>
    new this.constructor(Object.assign({}, product, {
      decay: decay
    }));

  this.build = () => Object.assign({
      lifespan: 255,
      decay: 1
    },
    product);
};

function MoveableBuilder(product) {
  this.at = (...coordinates) =>
    new this.constructor(Object.assign({}, product, {
      coordinates: coordinates
    }));

  this.facing = (...vector) =>
    new this.constructor(Object.assign({}, product, {
      vector: vector
    }));

  this.build = () => Object.assign({
    coordinates: [],
    vector: []
  }, product);
}

console.info(new MoveableBuilder().at(1, 1).facing(2, 1).build());

console.info(new ParticleBuilder().at(1, 1).build());
```